# Error on Reports while preview the designer screen Winforms Devexpress?

Tags: winforms, devexpress, report

Hi I attached new data source to reports(Winforms Devexpress) then I bind value label if i click preview it showing error as "error when trying to populate datasource, following exception was thrown your network access was interrupted. " ? help me

[image]

Comment: do you still have some of your controls bound to the old data source?

Comment: Before i used same data source to forms & reports i get this error so now I create new data source and bind to reports, still same error exists. what is the problem in this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is problem with my Access database so I just deleted and created new Access database and now working properly.